# Log method enter and exit in Scala

Tags: scala, logging, akka

Is there a simple way to implicitly log method enter and exit points in Scala akka?

For ex:

```
def method1(param1: String) {
//do something
}
```

Should log like

```
2019-12-18 12:57:27,311 [method1:start] INFO  param1 = "INPUT STRING"
2019-12-18 12:57:27,311 [method1:end] INFO  param1
```

Comment: If your point is to track each and every function call or message passing through Akka actors, I'll suggest you give a look at things like https://kamon.io/docs/latest/instrumentation/akka/

Answer (score 2):

Akka provides mechanisms for tracing messages between actors, but there is nothing to help log standard methods like this.

You can write a simple method to wrap the body of the original method:

```
def logInOut[T](f: => T) = {
  println("Enter") 
  val res = f  
  println("Leave")
  res
}

def method1(param1: String) = logInOut{
  println(param1)
}
```

This will print

```
Enter
Hello
Leave
```

Beyond that you would need to write a macro and annotate the method appropriately.